# How to use Apache Commons FTPClient for remote directory listing?

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net, suse

I am creating an instance of FTPClient & on that instance using the method listFiles(dirname).

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect("my-server-ip-address");
ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(20000);
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftpClient.login("myUser", "myPswd");
ftpClient.setKeepAlive(true);
final FTPFile[] listedFiles = ftpClient.listFiles(dirname);
```

This listFile() operation is throwing the exception "java.io.IOException: Unable to determine system type - response: 500 SYST not implemented"

But when I set the SYST type as UNIX before calling the connect on the ftpClient object using the FTPClientConfig as below

```
FTPClientConfig conf = new FTPClientConfig(FTPClientConfig.SYST_UNIX);
ftpClient.configure(conf);
```

Then SocketTimeoutException is thrown

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
```

The FTP Server is running on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (x86_64).

Are there any more configuration that needs to be done to successfully list the files in the FTP Server.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: just to be sure, have you tested that your FTP server has correct setup?

Comment: Yes the FTP Server has the correct setup, because I am successfully able to do remote directory listing using plain old java.net.Socket classes but I want to use Apache Commons FTPClient as it takes care of lot of underlying details.